# JAVA: How to check if all in objects array are objects of a subclass?

Tags: java, arrays

I got an array with Objects. Now I want to check if all of those Objects are instance of MyObject.

Is there a **better** option **than this**:

```
boolean check = true;
for (Object o : justAList){
  if (!(o instanceof MyObject)){
    check = false;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you also provide the example array?

Comment: @ChrisSprague idk, I don't want to have a loop there, because I loop through it after that again.

Comment: _because I loop through it after that again_ Can't you check it in the same loop???

Comment: Can't you then merge these two loops?

Comment: @AbishekManoharan I don't want to do something if there is any object from the superclass in it. Kind of Transanction Style: do it witch every or none.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't like the loop, you can always do this in Java 8:

**Using ArrayList**

```
List<Object> justAList = new ArrayList<>();
// Add items here...
return justAList.stream().allMatch(o -> o instanceof MyObject);
```

**Using normal array**

```
Object[] justAList = new Object[10];
// Set items here...
return Arrays.stream(justAList).allMatch(o -> o instanceof MyObject);
```

**EDIT:**

The above suggestion will only be useful to you if you want to perhaps improve code readability and/or make it more succinct.  But don't think that it avoids having to perform a loop.  It will still perform a loop, you just won't see it. So don't expect this to perform any better than what you already have.

Comment: Well, you said `list`, so I assumed you were using an `ArrayList`.  I'll edit my post to give you both an `ArrayList` version, and an `array` version.  **EDIT:** Sorry, I just noticed that the text of your post did say array :)  It would have helped to have included the type in your code though.

Answer (score 1):

It might not relate to this particular problem, but it is a good practice to use polymorphism instead of checking the type in an `if` condition. Like

```
 public void handle(MyObject object) {
   doSomething
 }
 public void handle(Object object) {
   doSomething
 }


 handle(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, you could use a `List<MyObject>` and other Lists with their respective types in the first place instead of an `Object`-Array in which you put everything.